# $\|(I+A)^{-1}\| \leq \frac{1}{1-\|A\|)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices, functional-analysis, banach-algebras

I have the following problem, of which I have a slight problem to finish with the second part:

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $A \in B(X)$, $\|A\| < 1$. Prove that $(I+A)^{-1}$ exists and is given by:
\begin{equation}
(I+A)^{-1} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nA^n
\end{equation}

where the series is absolutely convergent in B(X). Show also that
$$\|(I+A)^{-1}\| \leq \frac{1}{1-\|A\|)}$$
\begin{proof}
We examine that the alternating series converges using the ratio-test. Now:Let's multiply

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nA^n$$ by (I+A):
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nA^n \cdot (I+A) &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nA^n + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nA^{n+1}\\
&=(I+A)-(A+A^2)+(A^2+A^3)-\ldots\\
&=I
\end{align*}
since $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nA^n  < \infty$ we know
$(I+A)^{-1}$ exists.

Now to show that
$$\|(I+A)^{-1}\| \leq \frac{1}{1-\|A\|)}$$:

From the result that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nA^n  < \infty$ we have
$$\|(I+A)^{-1}\|=\|\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nA^n\|=\|I-A+A^2-A^3\ldots\|$$

and now I would expect something with geometric progression, but I failed to achieve the right inequality.
I appreciate any help!

Comment: You can use the triangle inequality extended to infinite sums.

Comment: Note that the ratio test does not mean much in this context, nor does your "$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-A)^n < \infty$" as the left hand side is not even a number. Indeed to answer the first question you are supposed to use the result of the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that,

$$ || I-A+A^2-\dots|| \leq 1+||A||+||A^2||+ \dots \leq 1+||A||+||A||^2+ \dots\,. $$

since $||A^n||\leq ||A||^n $. Now, if $||A||< 1$, then you can sum the series on the far right which gives you the result you want.